# Application or object defined error when trying to change background and font colors

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to replace all of the conditional formatting of a spreadsheet (over 30 formatting rules). I have created a class module (called ConditionalFormatting) that has a series of subs for all the formatting rules, with one sub for each range that needs conditional formatting.
The only way I have thought to do this (open to suggestions) is by having the worksheet_change event call a sub in the ConditionalFormatting class called FormattingSubs which will call the correct sub to perform the formatting.

Here is the code for FormattingSubs:

```
Public Sub FormattingSubs(target As Range)
    'have logic here to call the right sub based on what target.address
    'is from the worksheet.change event

    Select Case target.Name.Name
        Case "head_pouch_lot_number"
            Call HeadPouchLotNumber(target)
        Case "head_consumed_pouch_lot"
            Call HeadConsumedPouchLot(target)
        Case "section_one_heading"
            Call SectionOneHeading
    End Select

End Sub
```

And here is the code for one of the formatting subs, HeadConsumedPouchLot: (note that the color variables are public constants defined in a separate module)

```
Public Sub HeadConsumedPouchLot(target As Range)
    Dim head_consumed_pouch_lot As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set head_consumed_pouch_lot = ActiveSheet.Range("head_consumed_pouch_lot")
    Set ws = target.Worksheet

    If target.address <> head_consumed_pouch_lot.address Then
        Set target = head_consumed_pouch_lot
    End If

    With ws.Range(target.address)
        If Range("section_one_heading").Value <> "" Then
            .Interior.ColorIndex = red
            .Font.ColorIndex = yellow
        Else
            .Interior.ColorIndex = lightgreen
            .Font.ColorIndex = black
        End If
    End With
```

The problem is that when it goes to actually set the color, it gives me the 1004 error: "Application-defined or object-defined error."

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: What worksheet is `target` on?

Comment: Which line does the error actually occurs?

Comment: If **"head_consumed_pouch_lot"** is a Named Range in the workbook, you can use `ThisWorkbook.Names("head_consumed_pouch_lot").RefersToRange` instead of ActiveSheet

Comment: @RusanKax As I am calling the    FormattingSubs    routine from the worksheet change event, target is on the worksheet the changed cell is on. In this case, "head_consumed_pouch_lot" is on Sheet 1, named "FA-201C."

Comment: @PatricK The code errors on the     .Interior.ColorIndex = <color>. It will error out under the If or the Else.

Comment: instead `=red` ,  try `= RGB (255,0,0)`  ;   and then do the same for the other colors by looking their rgb values

Comment: BGEORGE what are the actual value of the `red`, `yellow` etc? I ask because `.ColorIndex` are something very small. If it is like `RGB(R,G,B)` values, you cannot use `.ColorIndex` use `.Color` instead

Comment: Thanks @PatrickLepelletier for the reply. The problem lied in the protection of the sheet. Turns out I had to unprotect the sheet in order to make any changes to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem I figured out was that I needed to unprotect my sheet before I could make any changes to it! Thank you all for helping me look for answers.

Comment: This was helpful - Excel's behavior here is inconsistent in that VBA is allowed to make other changes to the comment's format but not the font color.  I suspect this is not by design, and it was definitely not obvious or intuitive that the sheet needed to be unprotected.  Unprotecting the sheet did fix the same problem for me.